# Preview refuses to open pdf file, incorrectly claiming a permission issue

Tags: finder, preview, permission

I had to force-quit Preview (it became unresponsive after trying to open a 200Mb animated gif), but after re-starting it, some files that were open before no longer open. Instead an error box pops up saying that

> The file “file.pdf” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have
>   permission to view it.

and

> To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and
>   choose File > Get Info.

(how can I generate an image of that error box?).

However, the file permissions are okay, finder generated the usual preview, and acroread can open the file. I suspect that Preview has generated some lock for this file somewhere, but I'm not sure where and how. OSX 10.9.5. (copying the file in a terminal to another one and trying to open that didn't help, as did changing permissions to read-write for everyone).

Comment: also seeing the same problem on macOs 13.5.1. Removing preview state folder didn't work. Restarting computer helps

Comment: the quarantine xattr seems to be the culprit.  Try 'ls -l@' and 'xattr -l' on the files.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After searching on the net I found a solution, following mainly [this suggestion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4892480), though only deleting a small sub-directory:

1. I removed the sub-directory `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`
2. I quit Preview and re-started it.

PS: In recent versions of macOS the save state is kept in `~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Preview.savedState`.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but the [original answer](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4892480?answerId=21527875022#21527875022) did. Thank you for pointing me here!

Answer (score 41):

quitting preview was enough to fix it for me.

Comment: Worked for me... strange bug

Comment: Just opening preview and quitting didn't work for me. But opening and then force quitting seemed to work for some reason.

Comment: I think preview just locks the resources and does not release it.. This solution is good :)

Comment: Well, this did not help with the original problem, as stated in the problem. So, this does not answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above on a file that couldn't "be opened because of permissions" except by preview; nothing worked. :(

I then checked the file permissions in terminal:

```
term> ls -laF ~/Desktop/BadFile.pdf

-rwxr--r--@  1 geowar  staff  199754545 Jun 12  2020 3D BadFile.pdf*
```

That should be good enough to read the file… but just in case

```
term> chmod +w+x ~/Desktop/BadFile.pdf

-rwxrwxrwx@  1 geowar  staff  199754545 Jun 12  2020 3D BadFile.pdf*
```

Still couldn't open it.

Then I checked to see if some other process already had the file open:

```
term> lsof | grep 'BadFile.pdf'

Preview   33967 geowar  txt       REG               1,13  199754545            22843389 /Users/Desktop/BadFile.pdf
```

Preview has it open… so… quit preview… and now I can open the file!

Weird…