# Screenshots and images won't open - Don't have permission to view it

Tags: macbook-pro

[image]

Every time I take a screenshot I try to open it, but it says that I don't have the permission. It's not only my screenshots; all the pictures that I save say that I don't have any permission to open it.

Can anyone please help me resolve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Could you screenshot the permissions for the file you're trying to open? Right-click the file, and choose Get Info. Then, screenshot the "Sharing & Permissions" section.

Comment: do I add the screenshot to my question

Comment: Yep! That way anyone else trying to answer the question has all the information they need.

Comment: Try this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209686/preview-refuses-to-open-pdf-file-incorrectly-claiming-a-permission-issue - it's for PDFs, but since your issue is with Preview, it might still work.

Comment: @Allan that won't work. I created an image with the same permissions as OP, and I'm still able to read and write to it.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -la ~/Desktop/Screen*`

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: @h.altaher Allan's comment is asking you to type the command into `Terminal`

Answer (score 2):

I solved the situation.  All I had to do was quit preview.

Comment: I just quit preview and its all working again. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I also just quit Preview, and now it's working again. Second time in 5 years, so not a frequent anomaly.