# Preview: "The original document can't be saved, so a duplicate with your changes has been created"

Tags: macos, permission, preview, catalina

When I edit a PNG file in my Minecraft resourcepacks folder (`~/Library/Application Support/minecraft/resourcepacks/my_resource_pack/.../.././texture.png`) with Preview.app I get the error

> The original document can't be saved, so a duplicate with your changes has been created.

How do I force preview to write the file?

I don't think it's protected in special ways, terminal lets me edit, overwrite, manipulate the file however I want without any errors or warnings about ownership/permissions at all.

The containing directory has permissions `drwxr-xr-x` and is owned by me (my user account), and the file has permissions `-rwxr-xr-x` before opening in Preview.app, and after attempting editing on the file in Preview.app macOS adds the extended attributes

```
com.apple.lastuseddate#PS         16 
com.apple.quarantine      22
```

to the file.

I just noticed that the `..` parent directory, and all directories in the tree between `..` and `minecraft/resourcepacks/my_resource_pack` (including `my_resource_pack`) have the extended attribute

```
drwx------@ 
    com.apple.quarantine     57
```

Is this the cause of the weird and annoying Preview.app behaviour?

Get Info GUI on the file and on every folder in the path to the file (starting with `~/Library/Application Support/minecraft`):

[image]

The above is different for `~/Library`, and `~/Library/Application Support`, which are

[image]

**I want to force Preview to write the original file, and not create a duplicate.** How can I do so?

Comment: What are the perms on the containing folder?

Comment: @Tetsujin perms on containing folder are `drwxr-xr-x`, but the perms on the folder containing that are `drwx------@` - I edited question

Comment: I recall I had a similar issue editing the Hosts file, which I cured by adding myself as an ACL with full perms to the enclosing structure. idk how you do it in Terminal, I did it with the GUI & Get Info.

Comment: @Tetsujin in the Get Info GUI on the `drwx------@` folders, in Sharing & Permissions it says my user account has read/write permissions.

Comment: You can run `xattr -rd com.apple.quarantine ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft` to remove the attribute. It's not needed anyway, so you won't loose anything trying.

Comment: Also, did you try https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209695/9058 ?

Comment: @nohillside that directory doesn't exist, and removing the quarantine attribute with your command doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: Saved Application State moved directly to ~/Library AFAIK, did you check there?

Comment: @nohillside `~/Library/com.apple.Preview` has no tab completions or ls | grep matches

Comment: Please help us a bit here :-) `~/Library/Autosave Information` and `~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.Preview.savedState` are only a few autocompletion tabs away

Comment: @nohillside `~/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/` I deleted the Preview savedState, no behavioural difference. `~/Library/Autosave Information ` is inaccessible

Comment: Quite late but worth a try: I'm in the same situation (different folder but same problem)...did you find a solution?