# How to avoid "You don't have the permission to view it" errors in Terminal

Tags: terminal, finder, permission

On Catalina I have the following problem: I get permission error on some files when I try to open them through Terminal. Take for example the file `1100_2022S2_final.pdf` which resides in a folder `past-exams`.

When I try to open it via Terminal with the `open` command like this:

[image: Open command in Terminal]

I get the following error:

[image: Permission error]

In Finder I can  open the file per double click without issues.

This happens to quite a few files.

I checked the Security & Privacy Preferences for the Terminal app and it has Full Disk Access:

[image: Security & Privacy Preferences]

How can I make sure that I can open *all* files from Terminal?

#### Update

A few more details:

1. The UNIX permissions of the file in question are:

   ```
    -rw-r--r--@ 1 user  group   215K 26 Mar 13:06 1100_2022S2_final.pdf
   ```
2. When I call the files as

   ```
    sudo open 1100_2022S2_final.pdf
   ```

   I get the same problem.

Comment: What's the location of the enclosing folder; and what are the file attribute/permissions on the file? Can you do `sudo open` ....?

Comment: The permissions of Terminal are not relevant, as Preview is producing the error message you attached

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209686/preview-refuses-to-open-pdf-file-incorrectly-claiming-a-permission-issue

Comment: This is not a problem in Terminal. It'll also happen in the Finder.

Comment: I have this problem too on Catalina. I can't pinpoint the reason, but it seems related to how old the files are or how long since Preview last opened them. For me, quitting the Finder works every time but is inconvenient.

Comment: I’ve run into this, and it’s not related to the age of the file. I have a script that generates custom shipping labels as PDFs, so they’re only seconds old. I print the PDF from the script using `lp` so it’s not high on my todo list to solve.

Comment: The issue is opening the PDF *from* Terminal

Comment: @benwiggy On sudo and permissions I will report back when I am at the machine again, but I assume the permissions are "normal", because from the Finder I have no trouble opening the file.

Comment: @Ezekiel Good point! But why _can_ I open the file from Finder into Preview then without Preview complaining?

Comment: @halloleo - I’ll bet you can open the containing folder of your PDF.  Type `open .` in the directory where your PDF resides and it should open the folder.  Does the folder open in Finder?

Comment: @benwiggy Regarding permissions and sudo see the update to the post.

Comment: @Ezekiel When I open the Finder window, _then_ find the file in the list and _then_ double-click it, the file does indeed open as expected in Preview. That is better than nothing, but this whole mousing clicking around was what I wanted to avoid...

Comment: Can you remove Full Disk Access from Terminal, reboot and then add it again?

Comment: Is this inside one of the 'protected' folders -- Documents, Desktop and Downloads? If you move the file to ~/Test, does the error still occur?

Comment: @halloleo definitely compelling arguments - I agree it's important to know whether this is in a special folder or iCloud, etc.

Comment: @benwiggy The file is in a sub-folder under my Dropbox  folder. When I _move_ it  to a `~/test` folder I still cannot open it from the Terminal. However when I _copy_ it I can!!! (The `ls` permissions of both, moved and copied file are the same.  Very wired!)

Comment: Are there any ACLs on the file? `ls -l@`

Comment: @benwiggy ACL are different: The one in Dropbox has a `com.dropbox.attrs` attribute set, the other one doesn't. I guess the issue might be Dropbbox related.

Comment: @nohillside Also Removing and readding Full disk Access seem to have fixed it for now. I'm sure it'll come back, but now I am giving up on it.